# How can I add CancellationToken to my Controller?

Tags: controller, cancellation-token

I know, there are lots of answers here about CancellationToken, but for my problem, I have not found any solution yet. I just want to cancel this call, when the user starts a new one:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getUsers")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetUsersAsync(string query)
{
    return await _userService.GetUsersAsync(query);
}
```

I found something like that, but I do not know where the cancellationToken come from and where I have to pass it from here:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getUsers")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetUsersAsync(string query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await _userService.GetUsersAsync(query, cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to cancel this call, when the user starts a new one

There isn't a good way to do that in a web API, which is generally stateless. So there's no (good) way to detect "when the user starts a new one".

This is normally done on the client side, where "when the user starts a new one" is easy to detect. The old request is cancelled and a new one is made.

Your web API can detect a request being cancelled by just taking a `CancellationToken`. The cancellation token is provided by ASP.NET and is triggered when a request is cancelled.

To respond to the cancellation request, the most common pattern is to just pass it down to whatever APIs you call. In this case your `GetUsersAsync` call would take a `CancellationToken` and pass it down to whatever DB API it uses.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am very new in this topic, could you explain to me exactly how to proceed?

Comment: @Michael: You should just take a `CancellationToken` as an action parameter and pass it down through your other methods.

Comment: You mean like I already did in my first article? But I don't understand where the request is canceled.

Comment: @Michael: ASP.NET signals the cancellation token when the request is cancelled. The request is cancelled by the client.

Comment: Do I have to pass the cancellation token from the frontend to the backend?

Comment: No; it's provided by ASP.NET.

Comment: Then I don't understand, where I get this CancellationToken in the controller from? Do you have a good source where I can read up on this topic?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cancellationtoken